# I want to create "Farm" instances through the users_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form to create new "farms" in the views/users/show.html.erb (because farms don't have their own views):

```
<div id="add">
  <%= form_for(:farm, :url => {:action => :create}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.label :region %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :region %>
    <%= f.label :north %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :north %>
    <%= f.label :east %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :east %>
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description, rows: "6" %><br />
    <%= f.label :categories %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :categories, rows: "1" %><br />
    <%= f.label :products %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :products, rows: "2" %><br />
    <%= f.submit "Vstavi" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The farms_controller issues a create action:

```
class FarmsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate

  def create
    @farm = current_user.farms.build(params[:farm])
    if @farm.save
      flash[:success] = "Farm created!"
      redirect_to 'users/show'
    else
      render 'users/show'
    end
  end
end
```

Of course when I tried to create a new farm in the view I got:

*Template is missing*

*Missing template users/create with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/media/rok/LOCAL DISC/Users/Koko/Documents/KMETIJE/kmetije/app/views"*

So then I added the create action also to the users_controller, but I am obviously doing something wrong:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @farms = @user.farms.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    Farm.create
    redirect_to :action => :show
  end
end
```

I should probably also show my routes file:

```
Kmetije::Application.routes.draw do |map|
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :farms, :only => [:create, :destroy]

  root :to => 'pages#home'

  match '/home', :to => 'pages#home', as: 'home'
  match '/info', :to => 'pages#info', as: 'info'
  match '/signin', :to => 'sessions#new', as: 'signin'
  match '/users/1', :to => 'users#show', as: 'user'
  match '/signout', :to => 'pages#home', as: 'signout'
end
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Remplace `form_for(:farm, :url => {:action => :create})` with `form_for(:farm, :url => farms_path)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is making it submit to users/create, because you don't specify a controller, just an action.

```
<%= form_for(:farm, :url => {:action => :create}) do |f| %>
```

Because you're in a users controller action at the time it renders this page, it defaults to the current controller, ie users.  Try this

```
<%= form_for(:farm, :url => farms_path) do |f| %>
```

`farms_path` is basically "/farms", and a POST to this path is associated with the 'create' action.  (the `resources :farms` line in your routes sets this up)

It should then submit to farms#create instead, which is what you were expecting it to do in the first place.

Comment: Cool.  it's actually nicer to do `form_for(@farm)`, where @farm is a Farm object:  if @farm is an unsaved record it will submit to the farms#create action automatically, and if it's a previously-saved record it will submit to farms#update.